# Updating QGIS attribute table automatically

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I am writing a script that converts dxf drawing to a shapefile. Using my script now I can create a shapefile. Attribute table of that shapefile is initially empty and it has only one row. In that attribute table, there is a column called "Req_No". I make Req_No column value in to 23 and try the following code and it works.

```
selection=vl.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(' "Req_No"=23'))
for feat in selection:
  vl.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),1, '45')
  vl.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),2, 'H.M.P.jagath')
  vl.commitChanges()
```

Now I want to do this automatically. If I further explain, I want attribute table to update while the shapefile is forming. But initially attribute table columns are all empty.

How should I change the above mentioned code when Req_No column is Null?

I am using QGIS version 2.18.9.

Comment: Please do not write your titles in ALL CAPS.

Comment: Hi, it's hard to tell what exactly you want to do. Do you want to update an attribute value for all features where Req_No is 23? Or for all features which are there, regardless the Req_No attribute? I would recommend reading the [pyqgis developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword for a value you refer to as 'empty' is NULL. Therefore the below should work to select all features where the Req_No field is empty

`vl.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(' "Req_No" IS NULL')`)

Comment: This answer was flagged as very low quality, probably because it is a one-liner. I suggest formatting code as code (use the {} button) and  perhaps provide a brief explanation about how this code works. Tks.

Comment: Glad I could help. If I answered your question satisfactorily, please give it a tick to mark your question as answered

Comment: Actually i am new to this site.I was not aware of that before.I have given a tick to the answer.I am not allow to put a tick to the question.Therefore I am not sure Whether,  this is what you expected.Thank you.